# Can't scrape YouTube video's closed captions

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape a YouTube page for the subtitles. Unfortunately it isn't loading everything upon the request. I'm curious to know where I went wrong.

Query string:

```
https://www.youtube.com/timedtext_editor?action_mde_edit_form=1&v=Nxb2s2Mv6Pw&lang=en&bl=vmp&forceedit=captions&tab=captions
```

So I've figured out that this is the unique Url-I.D ... `Nxb2s2Mv6Pw` and I can just substitute it accordingly.

If I run the code below it doesn't catch the tag `<textarea yt-uix-form-input-textarea ...>`that I need it to locate.

I'm desperately trying to avoid using Selenium to capture this, as I've got a lot of links I need to iterate through and repeat the process. As you can tell by the code below, I've tried to incorporate a delayed time to wait for the page to load, but nothing.

```
import os
import codecs
import sys
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

channel = 'https://www.youtube.com/timedtext_editor?action_mde_edit_form=1&v=dto4koj5DTA&lang=en'
s = requests.Session()
time.sleep(5)
# s.headers['User-Agent'] = USER_AGENT
r = s.get(channel)
time.sleep(5)
html = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

for i in soup.find_all('div'):
    print(i)
```

Please advise.

Comment: there is no need to sleep after `Session()`. Server may send different page (with different tags and classes) when client doesn't use JavaScript (and has incorrect `User-Agent`). So you can turn off JavaScript in web browser and load page to see what you can get in BS. Or get `r.text` and save in file and open in text editor or in web browser - to see what you get.

Comment: @furas Hey again! Thank you for your input. Yeah, it's been a long night over here as its 3am right now and I'd caught that too late.
I'm using Jupyter notebook and have been monitoring everything via the r.text to see what comes in and it wasn't fetching what I needed. But I got the answer. Thank you again!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I tried scraping the page using `requests` and `lxml` but when iterating over the tags in the script, I could find no subtitles on the page (the textarea tag where the subtitles are do not show up in the script)
This is likely because YouTube uses javascript to load the subtitles.

Python's request library does not support javascript. You do however have a few options:

- Use selenium for scraping the subtitles (You said you would rather not do this.)
- Look into the POST and GET requests through your browser and try sending the request parameters needed to the url you traced the javascript to (May not always work if authentication is or dynamic tokens are used for parameters)
- #### Use **[youtube-dl](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/youtube_dl)** to download the subtitles.

  ***(This seems to be the easiest / most reliable way to go about this.)***

**[youtube-dl](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/youtube_dl)** is a command line utility, but you can also import it according to the docs on github.

There are a couple of ways you could go about this. I will be using the video you pointed to in your post for my examples:

```
youtube-dl --write-sub --skip-download --sub-lang en https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nxb2s2Mv6Pw
```

**With that being said, you can make a function in python to call the command:**

```
import os

def download_subs(video_url, lang="en"):
    cmd = [
        "youtube-dl",
        "--skip-download",
        "--write-sub",
        "--sub-lang",
        lang,
        video_url
    ]

    os.system(" ".join(cmd))


url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nxb2s2Mv6Pw"

download_subs(url)
```

**Alternatively, you could import `youtube_dl` from python directly and use it from there:**

```
import youtube_dl

def download_subs(url, lang="en"):
    opts = {
        "skip_download": True,
        "writesubtitles": "%(name)s.vtt",
        "subtitlelangs": lang
    }

    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(opts) as yt:
        yt.download([url])

url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nxb2s2Mv6Pw"
download_subs(url)
```

This creates a file in the working directory named

```
CNN 'Exposed' In Controversial Secret Video and Anita Sarkeesian's 'Punishment'...-Nxb2s2Mv6Pw.en.vtt
```

### The contents of the file look something like this:

```
WEBVTT
Kind: captions
Language: en

00:00:00.000 --> 00:00:01.500
You beautiful bastards

00:00:01.500 --> 00:00:07.200
Hope you having a fantastic Tuesday welcome back to the Philip Defranco show and let's just jump into it the first thing

00:00:07.200 --> 00:00:11.519
I want to talk about today one of the most requested stories of the day today is an update on the

00:00:11.889 --> 00:00:13.650
Craziness out of Vidcon yesterday

00:00:13.650 --> 00:00:19.350
Specifically we're talking about creator and panelist Anita Sarkeesian being on a panel calling someone in the crowd

...

...
```

Comment: You are welcome. youtube-dl is an awesome utility. I've been using it for some time now. It can be a very powerful application if used with the right command line arguments. You can find pretty extensive documentation on the command line arguments (and the rest of the module in general.) [HERE](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#embedding-youtube-dl). Happy programming!